# Parent process not running when calling fork(), function doesn't return

Tags: c, fork

I am writing the simplest of programs using the `fork()` system call. When I run the program, it seems as though the parent process stops running, and the function never returns.

```
int main() {
    int x = 100;
    int fork_result = fork();
    if (fork_result < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (fork_result == 0) {
        printf("Child value before: %d\n", x);
        x = 200;
        printf("Child value after: %d\n", x);
    } else {
        printf("Parent value before: %d\n", x);
        x = 300;
        printf("Parent value after: %d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output I get when run is:

```
Child value before: 100
Child value after: 200
```

Upon which the program continues to run indefinitely without returning. What is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: After fixing the multitude of errors and typos it did exactly what you'd expect for me, printing parent first, child second. Are you running this on Windows where `fork()` doesn't really work?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't copy/paste the code because I am running it on a Linux VM, Yes it compiles, that was just a typo on here.

Comment: Apart from the several typos, your code works fine. There's nothing wrong. Are you sure that's the exact version you are running?

Comment: Are you perhaps not flushing? Remember the default buffering is line-based only for TTYs.

Comment: @o11c the newlines at the end of each `printf` already take care of that, and even if wrong buffering was the problem, buffers would be automatically flushed on exit.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes, this is the exact version. What is even weirder is when I write another main function doing a very similar thing in the same file and rename the above function to something else, this new main function works properly.

Comment: @JackGreen that is... very strange. Could you also add the version that works? Also, where are you exactly running this? On a Linux VM on your PC? Have you tried adding a `sleep()` before the end of the parent process?

Answer (score 1):

When I compiled your code it failed on compile errors due to lack of headers and a few syntax errors. Fixing those it ran as expected for me. If you have your compiler set to ignore warnings or such strange things can happen when functions are not prototyped correctly.

For educational purposes I've put a few extra lines into your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main() {
    int x = 100;
    printf( "sizeof pid_t: %d\n", (int)sizeof(pid_t) );
    fflush( stdout );
    pid_t fork_result = fork();
    if (fork_result < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (fork_result == 0) {
        sleep(2);
        printf("Child value before: %d\n", x); 
        x = 200;
        printf("Child value after: %d\n", x); 
        printf("Child fork_result=%d\n", (int)fork_result);
        return(42);
    } else {
        printf("Parent value before: %d\n", x); 
        x = 300;
        printf("Parent value after: %d\n", x); 
        printf("Parent fork_result=%d\n", (int)fork_result);
        int   xit_stat;
        pid_t xit_wait = waitpid( fork_result, &xit_stat, 0 );
        printf("Parent sees exit=%d\n", xit_stat >> 8); 
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry... likely a mark-down error. Fixing.
Try it now.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. However, it still does not work for me unless I make the parent wait. Otherwise, the parent runs, returns, the shell prompt comes up, and then the child process runs and never returns.

Comment: @JackGreen: I've compiled under Lubuntu with gcc (often use Lubuntu in VMs).  What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using Debian VM and compiled using gcc.

Comment: @JackGreen  Don't have much to say aside that the fork() returning child pid returns really really fast, perhaps before the child even outputs.it's stuff.  This can cause a shell prompt before the child output happens unless the parent does some type of wait,...() call. The child's output then prints after the prompt. If users don't notice that the shell prompt precedes the child output you can be under the illusion that the parent is hung as they don't see a shell prompt; at least until they press ENTER to get a new prompt.

Comment: @JackGreen: Rereading your 0:10 comment. My comment above is an answer to a different problem. Why the child does not seem to return takes more thought.

The wait...() is a very good idea. To be very sure that the parent process has exited and the child is not returning/exiting print their process ids early on then use "ps -l" to find any still running processes. Look at the child's parent process id (PPID). Where we go from there depends on which PIDs are running. Also take a diversion through reading about zombie processes that show up if nobody reads the status of a child at exit.

Answer (score 1):

Found my same question here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23228/there-is-no-bash-indicator-prompt-after-a-forked-process-terminates

This gives a good answer and seems to be what is occurring.
Thanks everyone for your responses.